# Does chronic caffeine use increase or decrease blood flow to connective tissue?

Tags: tendinopathy, caffeine, blood-circulation, ligament

In the short term, the effects of caffeine are well studied both as a vasodilator and vasoconstrictor, but given that chronic use produces specific adaptations, is the long term effect of caffeine use reduced or increased blood flow to connective tissue?

https://www.independent.co.uk/life-style/health-and-families/health-news/drinking-coffee-significantly-improves-blood-flow-study-finds-8952276.html

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2748160/

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK202224/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With regard to underlying biological mechanisms, most research has been devoted to BP-raising effects of caffeine. However, there are many other substances in coffee, such as polyphenols, soluble fibre and potassium, which could exert a beneficial effect in the cardiovascular system. Although the precise nature of the relation between coffee and BP is still unclear, `most evidence suggests that regular intake of caffeinated coffee does not increase the risk of hypertension`.

for more education go to [this](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2605331/)

Comment: Welcome to MedicalSciences.SE. Is blood flow to the tissues only increased with higher blood pressure? I am not sure this answers the question.

Comment: Blood pressure is the two main factors:
1- Output of the heart
2- Vascular resistance : BP=output*VR ,and  Vascular resistance depends on the diameter of the vessel, the intensity of the flow, and the viscosity of the blood

Comment: But, is an increase of blood pressure all that is required to increase blood flow to connective tissues?

Comment: Look at the relationship above

Comment: Please review https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/q/28704/7951